The implementation of tbb::parallel_for gives a sigsev segmentation error
I was compiling a program named autoremesher on Ubuntu 22.04. It's an open source project, and I was requested to remove it's GUI. That I did and removed it's dependency from QT framework, except for the debugging part. However, since then I am facing a segmentation error received signal 11 (Segmentation fault) at tbb::parallel_for. I am sharing one such section. I am still new to this library and with average understanding of C++, so far I learned that the following call to parallel_for works by passing on a functor.
 class SurfaceParameterizer
    {
    public:
        SurfaceParameterizer(std::vector<ParameterizationThread> *parameterizationThreads) :
            m_parameterizationThreads(parameterizationThreads)
        {   
        }
        void operator()(const tbb::blocked_range<size_t> &range) const
        {
            for (size_t i = range.begin(); i != range.end(); ++i) {
                auto &thread = (*m_parameterizationThreads)[i];
                
#if AUTO_REMESHER_DEBUG
                qDebug() << "Island[" << thread.islandIndex << "]: resampling...";
#endif
                
                resample(thread.island->vertices, thread.island->triangles, thread.island->voxelSize, thread.islandIndex);

                const auto &vertices = thread.island->vertices;
                const auto &triangles = thread.island->triangles;
                
#if AUTO_REMESHER_DEBUG
                qDebug() << "Island[" << thread.islandIndex << "]: parameterizing...";
#endif
                ReportProgressContext reportProgressContext;
                reportProgressContext.islandIndex = i;
                reportProgressContext.autoRemesher = thread.autoRemesher;
                geogram_report_progress_tag = &reportProgressContext;
                geogram_report_progress_round = 0;
                geogram_report_progress_callback = ReportProgress;
                
                thread.parameterizer = new Parameterizer(&vertices, 
                    &triangles,
                    nullptr);
                thread.parameterizer->setScaling(thread.island->scaling);
                thread.parameterizer->parameterize();
                
                std::vector<std::vector<Vector2>> *uvs = thread.parameterizer->takeTriangleUvs();
#if AUTO_REMESHER_DEBUG
                qDebug() << "Island[" << thread.islandIndex << "]: quad extracting...";
#endif
                thread.remesher = new QuadExtractor(&vertices, 
                    &triangles, 
                    uvs);
                if (!thread.remesher->extract()) {
                    delete thread.remesher;
                    thread.remesher = nullptr;
                }
#if AUTO_REMESHER_DEBUG
                if (nullptr != thread.remesher) {
                    qDebug() << "Island[" << thread.islandIndex << "]: remesh done, vertices:" << thread.remesher->remeshedVertices().size() << " quads:" << thread.remesher->remeshedQuads().size();
                } else {
                    qDebug() << "Island[" << thread.islandIndex << "]: remesh failed";
                }
#endif
                delete uvs;
            }
        }
    private:
        std::vector<ParameterizationThread> *m_parameterizationThreads = nullptr;
    };


 tbb::parallel_for(tbb::blocked_range<size_t>(0, parameterizationThreads.size()),
        SurfaceParameterizer(&parameterizationThreads));

Here is a capture shot from the debugger

Here are few things I tried:

I tried removing it, and it works fine with out, although the process it not straightforward and there is literally tooo much integration for me to remove.
On Intel forum they suggest compiling with CXX flags such as --fno-builtin-memset or -fno-lifetime-dse
I tried compiling and running a simple code that works like a lambda function using tbb and it works fine, it was printing hello world a hundred times.

But to no avail. How can I resolve this?
